# What are the differences between rich:clientId, rich:component and rich:element?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I mean these three rich faces arguments:

```
#{rich:clientId('id')}
#{rich:element('id')}
#{rich:component('id')}
```

For example in these method call (actionListener):

```
 <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"
    actionListener="#{Bean.actionReset('#{rich:clientId('id')}')}"              
    oncomplete="jsFunction(this.value).text;" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have checked the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functions.html) of RichFaces to get the differences:

**rich:clientId**

> The rich:clientId('id') function returns the client identifier related
>   to the passed component identifier ('id'). If the specified component
>   identifier is not found, null is returned instead.

Example: you have a component with `id="myId"` in your page. The component is not at the top level of the structure. `rich:clientId(id)` will return the generated HTML id of the component. That could be something like `myForm:myPanel:myId`.

**rich:component**

> The rich:component('id') function is equivalent to the
>   RichFaces.$('clientId') code. It returns the client object instance
>   based on the passed server-side component identifier ('id'). If the
>   specified component identifier is not found, null is returned instead.
>   The function can be used to get an object from a component to call a
>   JavaScript API function without using the 
>   component.

This method will return a JavaScript object on which you can call some RichFaces functions. It depends on the component you refers.

**rich:element**

> The rich:element('id') function is a shortcut for the equivalent
>   document.getElementById(#{rich:clientId('id')}) code. It returns the
>   element from the client, based on the passed server-side component
>   identifier. If the specified component identifier is not found, null
>   is returned instead.

This method will return to you the HTML dom element for the given component id.